# Overwriting local repose using Xcode 8

Tags: git, xcode8

I was trying to install csv parser library to my swift project and it didn't work. I did it wrong and I messed my project. Now, my project won't even compile and several errors of "Undefined symbols for achitecture armv7" coming AWSMobileHubHelper file . So I'd like overwite the local repos with remote. How can I do that under Xcode 8. I tried discard changes expecting it revert back to last commit, but didn't work. The pull does not seem to overwrite either because my last commit does not have any error and I'm still getting those errors after the pull.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this can be done from XCode, but it can be achieved through the command line very easily.

`cd` to your repository and use the following command:

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Comment: Instead of taking the route, I resolve the issue by removing -objc parameter from Pods debug file.  And I think, Pods files are ignored and not being tracked. So the errors probably still remains. But thank you very much for your reply.